# Redirecting gdb output to stdout wihile using pwndbg

Tags: gdb

I am using `pwndbg` plugin with `gdb`. When any program that prints to `stdout` is run under `gdb`, I seem to not being able to see the output from the program during the debugging session. How can I redirect the output to the same terminal as that of `gdb` or to a different one?

Comment: are you sure that you are not missing the output in the vast information provided by pwndbg?

Answer (score 2):

```
set logging file ~/pwndbg.log
set logging on
```

Then run any command like `info functions`
You will find the output in the file specified.